# Assign a Object to another Object in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to assign an object to another other in jQuery but I am getting error. I am quite new to jQuery so all helps are much appreciated. Following is the code i am trying to do.

```
 while ($(obj)) {

        $(obj) = $(obj).children(":first");

    }
```

It is trying to traverse through a table.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: You cannot assign to the return value of a function, so `$(obj) = something;` does not make much sense. Why not use a local `obj` variable instead?

Comment: Cannot assign to a function result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(obj)` will always be considered as true, you are doing an infinite loop.

At least, you should do `while ($(obj).length)`, and you can't assign `$(obj).children(":first")` to `$(obj)`, `$(obj)` is not a variable. So maybe what you want to do is like below.

```
var element = $(obj);
while (element.length) {
    element = element.children(":first");
}
```

Comment: yes obj was making it a infinite loop . thanks i made it work

Comment: also one more quick question does it make sense if i assign obj = $(obj).children(":first"); ?